Yaw Pitch Roll of camera in local coordinate system
I retrieved camera properties from a bunch of Unreal scenes that I want to reproduce in Blender. The Unreal coordinate system is quite different: it is a left-handed one, cameras face +X instead of -Z like in Blender, etc.
What I want to do is simply to orient the camera with Yaw, Pitch, Roll, once I made it look in the +X direction.
Yaw is global/local, Pitch is local around the new pitch axis, Roll is local around the new roll axis. I am having more trouble than I would think, and I don't quite understand how Blender local axes work (I run into gimbal locks while I would think that the whole local coordinate system would rotate along with the camera).
In the end I'll do it programmatically, but a GUI answer is good too as I'm not worried about the coding part. Thank you in advance!

"the whole local coordinate system would rotate along with the camera" Rotating the camera does not rotate the coordinate system; the coordinate system is the static thing that camera rotation is measured relative to.  Rotating the parent rotates the local coordinate system.  I would expect this misconception to be the root of most of your problems.  Yaw/Pitch/Roll, in transformed axes, for a Blender camera, should be a ZXY Euler rotation mode: roll/pitch/yaw; backwards because you want it in transformed axes.  Conversion to different handedness is multiplying one rotation by -1.  Probably Y.
